# Cloud Backup for large TrueCrypt Container

Tags: backup, truecrypt

I have a TrueCrypt container (around 50GB) which has all of my backups inside.  I'd like to back up the container to cloud storage (not the files within), but obviously, I'd prefer not to re-upload 50GB every time a change is made to the container.  What would be the best cloud storage service for this scenario?  Ideally, I'm looking for a service with block-level updates and doesn't filesync (i.e. not dropbox, which incidentally does have block-level updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-to-securely-encrypt-your-files-in-the-cloud/) it seems Dropbox is the only cloud service able to locate the changed part of your TrueCrypt file container, and only upload these segments. It seems Google Drive and Microsoft Skydrive are unable to do this (at least as of May 2012); i.e. forcing you to upload the entire container with every change, which is not tractable:

> Dropbox can synchronize only the changed portions of large files,
>   while Google Drive and SkyDrive can only synchronize entire files (as
>   far as I can tell). This means that, if you have a 2GB TrueCrypt drive
>   and change a small file in it, Dropbox will upload a small portion of
>   the TrueCrypt file, while Google Drive and SkyDrive will re-upload the
>   entire 2GB file.

In any case, should you choose to store your data in the cloud, be aware that the NSA and similar organisations may have direct access to your encrypted data. If you change the data in your file container so that the encrypted patterns change, it significantly helps cryptographic attackers.